# Find the range for $f(x) = 2x^2 + 1 + \sqrt{3x+16}$

Tags: calculus, functions

$f(x) = 2x^2 + 1 + \sqrt{3x+16}$

$f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$

I need to find the range for this function.

I always have some problems for this type of requirements.

$2x^2 + 1 + \sqrt{3x+16}$ = $y$

How can I find $x$ that depends on $y$? How to approach this problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:

1. $f(0)=5.$
2. $f'>0$ on $[0, \infty)$, hence $f$ is strictly increasing.
3. $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty.$

Together with the intermediate value theorem, 1.,2. and 3. imply that $f([0, \infty)=[5, \infty).$

Comment: I understand. I always saw problems for which $f:R->R$ in that case I must calculate 2 limits ( x -> -∞ and x -> ∞ ) ?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $f(x)=2x^2+1+\sqrt{3x+16}$ is always increasing in the interval $[0,\infty)$ since the derivative is always positive. Or, you can argue that $x^2$ and $\sqrt{x}$ are both increasing functions in the interval $[0,\infty)$.

Hence we only need to find the lower bound $f(0)$.

\begin{align}
f(0)&=2(0)^2+1+\sqrt{3(0)+16} \\
&=1+\sqrt{16}\\
&=5
\end{align}

So the range of the function is $[5,\infty)$ or $\{f\mid f\ge 5, f\in \mathbb R \}$.

Comment: Increasing isn't enough, $3 - \frac 1 x$ is increasing and bounded above.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $2x^2 \geq 0$ and (since $x \geq 0$) $\sqrt{3x+16} \geq 4$. Using these facts, together with some well known properties of $y=x^2$ and $y=\sqrt{x}$, you can easily conclude that (for $x \geq 0$):
$$ 2x^2 + 1 + \sqrt{3x+16} \geq 5$$
that is:
$$ Im(f)= [5,+\infty) $$

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is continuous and the derivative is $4x+\frac{3}{2\sqrt{3x+16}} > 0$ therefore $f$ is strictly increasing so $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty.$ Now try to find the range.